# Rendering a partial in liquid layout (Rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, partial, liquid

I have a liquid template where I need to render a partial inside that.

Please note `@current_page.page_layout.content` will load the content from the DB.

My liquid layout file is as follows:

```
#layouts/public.html.erb
<%= Liquid::Template.parse(@current_page.page_layout.content).
render('page_content' => yield, 'page_title' => yield(:title)) %>
```

and following is my code, which includes the partial as well

```
{{page_content}}

{% include 'this_is_the_partial_name' %}
```

and I'm getting this error

```
Liquid error: This liquid context does not allow includes.
```

I tried searching the web and [found this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liquid-templates/IJpYVFaPwRo), but still I'm not sure what to enter for this code:

```
Liquid::Template.file_system = 
Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new(template_path) 
liquid = Liquid::Template.parse(template)
```

Answer (score 11):

Little late to the party.. but this is how you should use it:

In an initializer (like /config/initializers/liquid.rb) add:

```
template_path = Rails.root.join('app/views/snippets')
Liquid::Template.file_system = Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new(template_path)
```

Add your partial file, eg. `app/views/snippets/_partial_name.liquid`.

Now in your liquid template use:

```
{% include 'partial_name' %}
```